# Ways to reduce latency in importing data from csv files into MySQL Workbench when connected to an RDS MySQL db Instance

Tags: amazon-rds, mysql-8.0, mysql-workbench, aws-aurora

This question is a follow-up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75908413/extreme-latency-in-any-operations-performed-in-mysql-workbench-connections-to-rd/75908834?noredirect=1#comment133892686_75908834) I asked on Stack Overflow yesterday after answering my own question by creating a Aurora MySQL db Instance and establishing a connection between it and MySQL Workbench, and like all of the previous variations I have tried, this too failed to noticeably decrease the runtime required by the Table Data Import Wizard to import and load the three csv files containing the source data sets for my team's project.

Is there a way I can do this in the RDS tab on my Team's AWS account directly or some other way around having to go through MySQL Workbench perhaps? Or instead, should I install Microsoft SQL Server and create a new RDS db Instance using that engine instead?

Comment: Why does the CSV file have to go through the (presumably GUI) Workbench?  When I want to load data into RDS PostgreSQL, I use the command line client; I bet the mysql cli client would be faster for your needs.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, I don't know how to use command lines and terminals yet really to be honest, but perhaps this is a much needed wake up call!

Comment: What’s the difference between this question, and the seemingly same  question on SO?  That answer told you not to use Workbench because it’s slow, and now you’re here asking why Workbench is so slow.

Comment: Because my Workbench application did not have this issue when I was just using the MySQL Server I installed alongside it over the last few weeks. This problem began only when I first successfully established a connection in it to an RDS MySQL db Instance instead. SO, while I appreciate that the problem may be mostly on Workbench's end, that does not explain why it only began once I incorportated AWS's RDS service into the picture.

Comment: Have you pinged the db instance? More importantly, did you already create the indices on the Aurora database?

Comment: I have not pinged the db instance yet, no. This is still only my 3rd week using AWS now and we were not given any in depth instructions on using it either. Is pinging a db instance a simple task? And to answer your second question as well, unfortunately, the answer to that is also no.

Comment: `ping` is just `ping`.  You use it just like you'd ping any other device on a network.  As for adding the indices... **good**.  That slows down the import process.

Comment: @RonJohn I pinged the network and it said there were 4 packets sent and 0 received for a 100% loss.

Comment: Then "the network" might either be down or very problematic, and be a cause of the slowness.  I'd next run [WinMTR](https://github.com/White-Tiger/WinMTR) (a souped up combination of `ping` and `traceroute`.